# How to use facebook graph api for unread message counts?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an application to get the unread notification count for social medias (facebook, twitter)

Before api 2.4 what I'm suppose to do is to get permission from user to get their notification then do a

```
FBCount= new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/me/notifications?fields=unread",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                /* handle the result */
                            }).executeAsync().toString();
```

But at api 2.4 it seems like it's impossible to get it anymore ?

Is there any possible way to the number of unread messages ?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way in v2.4. If you read the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog you will see it was removed.